# Procfile for deploying django in Heroku "web: gunicorn [app name]:application -b xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8000"

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, procfile

I'm trying to deploy my app and the Profile seemed to be wrong and my app crashes before I can view it.

I tried to write this in the Procfile:
`web: gunicorn SC_BASIS:application -b 127.0.0.1:8000`

and I was expecting it to run since I previously had problems with `web: gunicorn SCBASIS.wsgi`

However, it still errors with the following message. I'm not sure what is wrong:

```
Starting process with command `gunicorn SC_BASIS:application -b 127.0.0.1:8000`
2023-12-22T22:28:22.256483+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-12-22 22:28:22 +0000] [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
2023-12-22T22:28:22.256752+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-12-22 22:28:22 +0000] [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (2)
2023-12-22T22:28:22.256788+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-12-22 22:28:22 +0000] [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2023-12-22T22:28:22.258739+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-12-22 22:28:22 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2023-12-22T22:28:22.259865+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to find attribute 'application' in 'SC_BASIS'.
2023-12-22T22:28:22.259934+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-12-22 22:28:22 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2023-12-22T22:28:22.280621+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-12-22 22:28:22 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2023-12-22T22:28:22.280808+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-12-22 22:28:22 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Worker (pid:7) exited with code 4
2023-12-22T22:28:22.281142+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to find attribute 'application' in 'SC_BASIS'.
2023-12-22T22:28:22.281204+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-12-22 22:28:22 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2023-12-22T22:28:22.300841+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-12-22 22:28:22 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Worker (pid:8) exited with code 4
2023-12-22T22:28:22.300880+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-12-22T22:28:22.300892+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 202, in run
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301100+00:00 app[web.1]: self.manage_workers()
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301151+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 571, in manage_workers
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301250+00:00 app[web.1]: self.spawn_workers()
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301269+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 643, in spawn_workers
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301371+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301397+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301463+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301481+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 533, in reap_workers
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301569+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.APP_LOAD_ERROR)
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301602+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'App failed to load.' 4>
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301611+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301611+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301619+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301620+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301630+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301676+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301743+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301752+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301841+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301864+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 236, in run
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301959+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
2023-12-22T22:28:22.301975+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2023-12-22T22:28:22.302015+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2023-12-22T22:28:22.302035+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2023-12-22T22:28:22.302101+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2023-12-22T22:28:22.302128+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2023-12-22T22:28:22.302243+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2023-12-22T22:28:22.302260+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 396, in stop
2023-12-22T22:28:22.302332+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2023-12-22T22:28:22.302350+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2023-12-22T22:28:22.302404+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2023-12-22T22:28:22.302420+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 533, in reap_workers
2023-12-22T22:28:22.302502+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.APP_LOAD_ERROR)
2023-12-22T22:28:22.302530+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'App failed to load.' 4>
2023-12-22T22:28:22.469709+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-12-22T22:28:22.497223+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-12-22T22:28:55.730377+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=scbasis-a8315e618fcf.herokuapp.com request_id=ee714226-d27e-4c0e-8370-b5520ea232c4 fwd="216.9.110.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-12-22T22:28:56.220149+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=scbasis-a8315e618fcf.herokuapp.com request_id=f88097dd-caeb-439d-bf21-933a6ce30c42 fwd="216.9.110.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include your app_name. What you need is your project_name. In your Procfile, enter and save this `web: gunicorn project_name.wsgi --log-file -`